# Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

I have added the latest version of NHibernate but when I compile, this error occurs.
Somebody tell me how to solve the problem. In `web.config`, I also added this:

```
 <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.4000" newVersion="4.0.0.4000" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, there are projects/dll referencing version *3.3*, so your redirect is not enough:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.4000" newVersion="4.0.0.4000" />
```

This should work:

```
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.4000" newVersion="4.0.0.4000" />
```

see that the range is now including the missing verison **3.3.1.4000** not only *3.0.0.4000*

Comment: this work but another exception occurs 
{"Method 'PostInstantiate' in type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory' from assembly 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle, Version=2.1.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' does not have an implementation.":"NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory"}

Comment: Yeap, it seems that you have to apply lot of binding Recirect... or better - if possible - rebuild these projects to be using NHibernate 4.+ The exception you showed says: There is a code which does need some part from NH3 (currently removed). That must be rewritten and rebuild... not nice ... But.... sorry I do not have better ;(